# Why does not work relationship many-to-many?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My database contents the 3 tables:

```
users           roles        role_user
id | name       id | name    user_id | role_id
```

**Role model:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
   // TODO
}
```

**User Model:**

```
 public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function getUsers(){
        $users = User::all();

        foreach($users->roles as $item){
            dd($item);
        }
    }
```

When I call method `getUsers()` I get error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$roles

So, I need to get all roles of user, it might be some values for each user.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users is an Eloquent collection, that's why the roles method doesn't exist.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
public function getUsers() {
    // eager load roles to prevent n+1 query problem
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        foreach ($user->roles as $item) {
            echo $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please, why my solution was not work? And what did you change?

Comment: And how can I display `$user->roles` directly inside template?

Comment: The Eloquent Collection ($users) doesn't have the method (roles) that you declared in the User model.